# quartz_jobs.xml is parsed with error in xml document (x,y)

Tags: .net, xml, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I'm trying to install quartz.net 2.2.4 and run a helloworld simple job. But I'm not able. quartz_jobs.xml is not parsed. It is obviously read but quartz fails to parse it. Log gives me the following error each time I try to launch scheduler in my console application.

```
ERROR | Error scheduling jobs: Error in xml document (2,2)
```

jobs.xml is a valid xml. moreover any other valid xml will give me the same error. If i try to feed quartz with invalid xml it shows something like

```
ERROR | Error scheduling jobs: Element XXX is missing an end tag
```

Please advise.

Here is app.config

```
<configSections>
<section name="quartz" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler, System, Version=1.0.5000.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
<section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog" />
<sectionGroup name="common">
  <section name="logging" type="Common.Logging.ConfigurationSectionHandler, Common.Logging" />
</sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<quartz>
  <add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceName" value="MySchedular" />
  <add key="quartz.threadPool.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz" />
  <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadCount" value="2" />
  <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadPriority" value="2" />
  <add key="quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold" value="60000" />
  <add key="quartz.plugin.xml.type" value="Quartz.Plugin.Xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin, Quartz" />
  <add key="quartz.plugin.xml.fileNames" value="quartz_jobs.xml" />
```

My quartz_jobs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<job-scheduling-data
xmlns="http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/JobSchedulingData"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/JobSchedulingData 
    http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/job_scheduling_data_1_8.xsd"
version="1.8">
<schedule>
<job>
  <name>SimpleJob</name>
  <group>GroupDummy</group>
  <description>This is a simple job</description>
  <job-class>App.Scheduler.SimpleJob</job-class>
</job>
<trigger>
  <cron>
    <name>dummyTriggerNameA</name>
    <job-name>JobA</job-name>
    <job-group>GroupDummy</job-group>
    <cron-expression>0/5 * * * * ?</cron-expression>
  </cron>
</trigger>
</schedule>
</job-scheduling-data>
```

Here is Console Application Main

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            ISchedulerFactory sf = new StdSchedulerFactory();
            IScheduler sched = sf.GetScheduler();
            sched.Start();
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong xml for version 2.0.

Change the job-scheduling-data element to this and if you're using a validating editor you'll see the error:

```xml
<job-scheduling-data xmlns="http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/JobSchedulingData" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0">
```

Here is an example quartz_jobs.xml that you can start with for version 2:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!-- This file contains job definitions in schema version 2.0 format -->

<job-scheduling-data xmlns="http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/JobSchedulingData" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0">

  <processing-directives>
    <overwrite-existing-data>true</overwrite-existing-data>
  </processing-directives>

  <schedule>

    <job>
        <name>sampleJob</name>
        <group>sampleGroup</group>
        <description>Sample job for Quartz Server</description>
        <job-type>Quartz.Server.SampleJob, Quartz.Server</job-type>
        <durable>true</durable>
        <recover>false</recover>
    </job>

    <trigger>
      <simple>
        <name>sampleSimpleTrigger</name>
        <group>sampleSimpleGroup</group>
        <description>Simple trigger to simply fire sample job</description>
        <job-name>sampleJob</job-name>
        <job-group>sampleGroup</job-group>
        <misfire-instruction>SmartPolicy</misfire-instruction>
        <repeat-count>-1</repeat-count>
        <repeat-interval>10000</repeat-interval>
      </simple>
    </trigger>
  </schedule>
</job-scheduling-data>
```